# Convert string into integer without losing zero from lead, IN android JAVA

Tags: java, string, integer

```
String number="00010001000100";

int con=Integer.parseInt(number.toString());

Output=10001000100.
```

Note: I want `00010001000100` as Integer without losing any zero even if there are more zero in lead like `0000000100010001`. I want exact conversation into integer.
      I can't set zero manually as i am working with binary and hex.

Comment: What do you mean by an integer with a leading zero?

Comment: Why not `Integer.parseInt(number, 2);` and `Integer.toBinaryString(yourNum);`/`Integer.toHexString(yourNum);`?

Comment: Are you trying to get the binary representation of a number?

Comment: I do not understand your logic of having multiple zeros before the integer? Could you explain that?

Comment: I think our main question is -

1. Like fzzfzzfzz asked, what do you mean by integer with a leading zero?

2. What exactly do you want to do with that integer, I do not think what you are looking for is really an integer, but I may be wrong since I do not know the complete requirement.

Comment: You're mixing two things - the integer representation in binary and its actual value (in whatever base you want, but usually base 10). You should just convert the string into an integer from the base 2, and if you need its String representation in binary, use toBinaryString and pad with the number of 0's requested if any.

Comment: Look i am storing a numer inString as binary as for example: 0001000100. Now i want to convert this to hex, but as soon i convert into Integer the leading zero are omitted. I want the exact same number in integer for  String hex = Integer.toHexString(con);

Comment: Yes i have number which represent binary and it is stored into String as  i would like to convert it into Integer without missing any leading 0.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to know how many digits are in a number even if it has leadding zeros. For example 001 should equal 3 not 1 ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

> I can't set zero manually as i am working with binary and hex.

Assuming you are trying to convert number to binary and trying to retain the leading zeros you can try this:

```
String.format("%16s", Integer.toBinaryString(yournumber)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Here `yournumber` is an integer value.

If you want to convert string to number without removing the leading zeros then you can try this:

```
yournumber.ToString("D16");
```

Here D is the decimal and 16 is the amount of digits.

Comment: I am trying to convert string into integer without losing any leading zero.

Comment: @DhavalPatel:- Updated my answer. Hope that helps! ALso note that  int is meant to represent a mathematical integer. The numbers 00009999 and 9999 are exactly the same number, mathematically. So just by int its not possible

Comment: Look in my application i am asking to input a binary number through a toggle buttons, after entered i collect each single input and concatenate into a single string to complete a binary input which is actually stored into string format. Now i would like to convert into hex from inputed data , which is actually a sting. So my big question is how do i convert hex from string data posing to be binary. As for example if string contain 00100, i want hex conversion of binary 00100.

Comment: I want something like this, if string contain 00100, i want hex conversion of binary 00100, if it is 0001000000110, i want hex conversion of binary 0001000000110 do you have any solution?

Comment: @DhavalPatel:- Try this  `public static String binaryToHex(String str) {
   return String.format("%16X", Long.parseLong(str,2)) ;
}`

Comment: @DhavalPatel:- Or even `String bin = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(binOutput, 2));` will work

Answer (score 0):

if you store '010' in int datatype it will treat as an octal.
For eg.

int a=010;
System.out.println(a);
Output: 8
It will treat it as OCTAL number

So you cannot store a number beginning with 0 in int as compiler will typecast it. Therefore for that you have to work with Strings only :)

Comment: Then how am i support to convert into hex with integer  String hex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(number));

Comment: I have a string which represent an binary number like 0011000100, now i want to convert that into hex.Like binary to hex. So for that i need an exact input. Please help.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Please state your problem clearly :)

Comment: So basically you want to convert BINARY to hexadecimal right?

Comment: Look in my application i am asking to input a binary number through a toggle buttons, after entered i collect each single input and concatenate into a single string to complete a binary input which is actually stored into string format. Now i would like to convert into hex from inputed data , which is actually a sting. So my big question is how do i convert hex from string data posing to be binary. As for example if string contain 00100, i want hex conversion of binary 00100.

Comment: Please specify input ..and output properly ...and then I can help you ....

Comment: I want something like this, if input string contain 00100, i want hex conversion of binary 00100, if it is 0001000000110, i want hex conversion of binary 0001000000110. if string contain 00000100001000 as value stored, then i want hex conversion of binary 00000100001000.

Comment: So you make a program of converting the STRING: 00100 to Deciaml first...
and then convert that Decimal into hexadecimal

Comment: public static void abc(String binary)
        {
            int value=0;
            int count=0;
            for(int x=binary.length()-1;x>=0;x--)
            {
                value+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(x)+"")*Math.pow(2,count++);
            }
            
            String hexa=Integer.toHexString(value);
            System.out.println(hexa);
        }

Answer (score 0):

public static void abc(String binary)

```
    {
        int value=0;
        int count=0;
        for(int x=binary.length()-1;x>=0;x--)
        {
            value+=Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt(x)+"")*Math.pow(2,count++);
        }

        String hexa=Integer.toHexString(value);
        System.out.println(hexa);
    }
```

Comment: `Math.pow` is a bad suggestion for this task. (Uses `double`, inefficient, complicated.) Better use bit shifting or just multiplication.